# How can I highlight code differences

Tags: support

Sometimes a code snipplet included in the original question is *almost* working, but not quite, and only requires a small fix. But sometimes it is important to show contextually where this fix goes (rather than just say "substitute X with Y"). As an example, in one of [my recent answers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2543/multiply-defined-labels-warnings-with-frame-labels-in-beamer-with-againframe/2546#2546) the "fix" is only 11 additional characters out of more than 100. I think it will increase clarity if the differences are highlighted.

> Is there a easy way to high light code differences?

I ask because in a "code" block, the **bold** and *italics* mark-ups are ignored.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since Jukka forgot to include the *source code* for his answer, here it is:

```
<pre>
Foo <b><i>bar</i></b> baz
Foo <s>baz</s> bah
</pre>
```

Comment: I made it CW so that people can click "edit" to see it. :)

Comment: (... and it seems that I forgot that there is some kind of reputation threshold needed to edit CW posts. Apologies.)

Comment: @JukkaSuomela: And, as it turns out, it's actually possible to get to that post's revision history by clicking on your name or the date ... though I can't actually find a way to get to *this* post's history, for some reason. (They should really just add a "history" link next to "link" and "flag" ...)

Answer (score 4):

You might use comments in your code like:

```
% Look! Here is what I changed!
```

I know that it doesn't sound like an elegant solution, but so far the SE engine doesn't include a `diff` tool :)

Answer (score 3):

Examples:

```
Foo bar baz
Foo baz bah
```